# How can I show a web part on a list view web part page only when viewing the contents of a folder?

Tags: web-part

I have a document library with several folders. I have a content editor web part that I would like to display only when viewing the contents of one of these folders. I'm sure I could come up with a javascript solution, are there any "better" solutions available?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Query String Url filter and filter your list view by a matching folder ID.